# Get an JSON invalid error trying to create a sharepoint document library with javascipt

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharepoint, https

This is a part of my code, the problem is when I try to use an special character like an spanish accent in the title property. 
It work fine with normal characters.

```
const jsonData = JSON.stringify({
    '__metadata': {
        'type': 'SP.List'
    },
    'OnQuickLaunch': true,
    'BaseTemplate': 101,
    'Title': name
});


const options = {
    hostname: self.host,
    port: 443,
    path: baseUrl + '/_api/web/lists?&$expand=DefaultViewUrl',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose; charset=utf-8",
        "accept-language": "es-ES,es;q=0.9",
        "X-RequestDigest": self.digest,
        'Content-Length': jsonData.length,
        'Cookie': self.AuthCookie1 + "; " + self.AuthCookie2
    }
}
```

When trying to call the https post request
The response is

```
{ 
   "error":{ 
      "code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
      "message":{ 
         "lang":"es-ES",
         "value":"JSON no válido. Se encontr\u00f3 un fin de entrada inesperado en el contenido JSON. No se cerraron todos los ámbitos de objeto y de matriz."
      }
   }
}
```

I don´t know how to create a sharepoint document library with accent in the title.
Debugging the netkork call, in chrome inspector, of the same process directly from the sharepoint create library form, i don´t see differences of headers or body call.

Answer (score 0):

Tested json data to create document library.

Post to

```
_api/web/lists
```

Body:

```
    { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 101,
 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My Documents Library','OnQuickLaunch': true, 'Title': 'RestAPIDocument' }
```

Comment: Ok, but try with another title, one wich contains accents, or some special character.. ex.:"Título año I"